# Restrict access to Members from instances of the same class

Tags: c#

Consider the following Code:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    private Person? _brother;
    private int _age;

    public Person(string name, int age, Person? brother = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        _age = age;
        _brother = brother;
    }
    
    public int GetAgeOfBrother()
    {
        if (_brother is null) {
            return -1;
        }
        return _brother._age;
    }
}

var p1 = new Person("Bob", 30);
var p2 = new Person("Alice", 35, p1);
Console.WriteLine(p2.GetAgeOfBrother());
```

Here Alice can see the age of Bob although it is private, because she is instance of the same class. What do I have to do, so that a member can really be only accessed by the exact instance it is member of and the line `return _brother._age;` results in a compiler error?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: At compile time you can not. At runtime you can do that by making a type check against: new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType

Comment: @Peter OP can't do that because _age is a field.

Comment: It's probably possible to write a Roslyn analyzer for this, I guess. That's beyond the scope of my experience to advise though. It's probably not worth the effort.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar You can do the type check inside the GetAgeOfBrother.

Comment: @Peter That seems redundant when OP wants to prevent `_brother._age` being called from `GetAgeOfBrother()`.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Since both _brother and _age are declared as private they can be only accessed through the GetAgeOfBrother method.

Comment: @Peter I think you've misunderstood the question. _"Here Alice can see the age of Bob although it is private, because she is instance of the same class. What do I have to do, so that a member can really be **only accessed by the exact instance it is member of** and **the line return _brother._age; results in a compiler error?**"_. The only way I could see that OP could maybe achieve this is through a Roslyn analyzer.